# How to get a notification when frames are being played of a video file, using iOS AVFoundation?

Tags: ios, video, delegates, avfoundation

I am trying to process frames of a video that is loaded from a file (not a camera stream).

To do that, I've loaded the video (currently a test mp4 that's in the bundle, although I plan to have this be an external url).

I've read through a lot of documentation and tutorials on AVFoundation, and I've found a number of different suggestions, but none of them have worked.  What I was hoping was to find a delegate method or a notification when a frame changed, but I think these do not actually exist (possibly because they would be too slow to handle frame streams).

Here's what I have so far.  I need the [self doImageProcess:] selector to run every time an image is rendered from a video stream.  How can this be done?

(I will post fully working code once this is working properly)

```
#import <AVFoundation/AVFoundation.h>

@implementation VTViewController

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    // load mp4

    NSURL *theURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"video" ofType:@"mp4"]];

    AVAsset *avAsset = [AVAsset assetWithURL:theURL];
    AVPlayerItem *avPlayerItem =[[AVPlayerItem alloc] initWithAsset:avAsset];

    avPlayer = [[AVPlayer alloc] initWithPlayerItem:avPlayerItem];


    CMTime interval = CMTimeMake(33, 1000);  // 30fps
    id playbackObserver = [avPlayer addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:interval queue:nil usingBlock: ^(CMTime time) {
        // get image
        [self doImageProcess:nil];
    }];

   img1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];
   [self.view addSubview:img1];


    avPlayerLayer =[AVPlayerLayer playerLayerWithPlayer:avPlayer];
    [avPlayerLayer setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 480, 320)];//self.view.frame];

    [self.view.layer addSublayer:avPlayerLayer];
    [avPlayer seekToTime:kCMTimeZero];
    [avPlayer play];

}


- (void)doImageProcess:(UIImage *)theImage {

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.view.bounds.size, 1.0, 1.0);
    [avPlayerLayer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
    UIImage *img = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    [arrImages addObject:img];

    [img1 removeFromSuperview];
    img1 = nil;
    img1 = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];
    [self.view addSubview:img1];


    if ([arrImages count] > 4)
        [arrImages removeObjectAtIndex:0];

}
```

Comment: have you solved that?

Answer (score 1):

The `addPeriodicTimeObserverForInterval:queue:usingBlock:` method of `AVPlayer` may help. It can execute a block of code at a particular time interval of playback.

Comment: I have done that (see above edits) but the image is not being captured properly from the layer.  Any suggestions?

Comment: I would suggest asking that as a new, more specific question. You will get much better answers.